# Regex capture phrase, plus word before and word after

Tags: python-3.x, regex, python-re

With Python `re`, I'm trying to capture a phrase, plus the word before and word after in a single return.

I.e.
From the sentence...

`We want to see this phrase here and then again!`

 Return

 `see this phrase here`

The closest I have gotten is ...

```
>>> s = 'We want to see this phrase here and then again!'
>>> re.search("\w*\sthis phrase\w*\s",s)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(11, 27), match='see this phrase '>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your regex since you're matching `\w*\s` after search term it is matching 0 words and a single whitespace after your search term.

You may use this more robust regex to handle cases when your search term is at the start of a line or at the end of a line:

```sh
(?:^|\w+\s+)this phrase(?:\s+\w+|$)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jgQCPt/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?:^|\w+\s+)`: Match start position or a word followed by 1+ whitespaces
- `this phrase`: Match search term
- `(?:\s+\w+|$)`: Match end position or 1+ whitespace followed by a word

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a simple typo. Your attempt looks for `this phrase` immediately followed by more word characters (so *phrases* or *phraseology* too) followed by a space, but you say you want them in the opposite order.

```py
"\w*\sthis phrase\s\w*"
```

This still won't work correctly for "This phrase has no space before it." or "However, this phrase, unfortunately, is bracketed by punctuation." so it might still need more work on the design if you want to process free-form text.

Comment: IMO, it should be `\w+\sthis phrase\s\w+`. Also, it looks like the OP is not looking for a case-insensitive search; therefore, your example should be `"this phrase has no space before it."` instead of `"This phrase has no space before it."`.